# Is there a way to pass a custom type from C# to Oracle using System.Data.OracleClient?

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, stored-procedures

I was searching online for a solution to passing a string array to a stored procedure in Oracle. The "easy" but messy way was using a comma delimited string.

I had found a sample based on which I created my own type of TABLE of VARCHAR2(200).

I understood that I could use a constructor created "behind-the-scenes" by Oracle to give a list of values that would, in the PL/SQL, be treated as a TABLE I could iterate through.

But when I got to the C# I saw that there is no way for me to create an OracleParameter object that would allow me to use this implicit constructor.

All the samples I'm finding online for now are dealing with Oracle Data Adapter, none say anything about System.Data.OracleClient.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure but I found this article: http://bit.ly/9ynJiA Hope it helps

Comment: I know that with Oracle ODP.NET provider you could easily deal with custom types, but I doubt that with data provider from Microsoft you can achieve this.

Comment: It says something about using `DbType.Object` with the base ADO.NET interfaces.

Comment: Diadistis, as far as I can understand, this is based on using ODP.

Comment: @Alex - yes, that's the picture I'm starting to see.

Comment: @Frankie Simon, I worked with `MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY` type through ODP.NET two or three years ago. If you wish I could post some examples here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every resource I find sends me to ODP, and adds that I shouldn't bother with the Microsoft provider since it's going to be deprecated in .NET 4.

I think I'm giving up on this for now, thanks for the help Alex and Diadistis.