# Parsing pipe delimited string into columns?

Tags: oracle, plsql, tokenize

I have a column with pipe separated values such as:

'23|12.1| 450|30|9|78|82.5|92.1|120|185|52|11'

I want to parse this column to fill a table with 12 corresponding columns: month1, month2, month3...month12.

So month1 will have the value 23, month2 the value 12.1 etc...

Is there a way to parse it by a loop or delimeter instead of having to separate one value at a time using substr?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can fill a variable of my own created data type within Oracle PL/SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903142/how-can-fill-a-variable-of-my-own-created-data-type-within-oracle-pl-sql)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `regexp_substr` (10g+):

```
SQL> SELECT regexp_substr('23|12.1| 450|30|9|', '[^|]+', 1, 1) c1,
  2         regexp_substr('23|12.1| 450|30|9|', '[^|]+', 1, 2) c2,
  3         regexp_substr('23|12.1| 450|30|9|', '[^|]+', 1, 3) c3
  4    FROM dual;

C1 C2   C3
-- ---- ----
23 12.1  450
```

With a loop in PL/SQL:

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL> DECLARE
  2     p_tsv  VARCHAR2(1000) := '23|12.1| 450|30|9|78|82.5|92.1|120|185|52|11';
  3     l_item VARCHAR2(100);
  4  BEGIN
  5     FOR i IN 1 .. length(p_tsv) - length(REPLACE(p_tsv, '|', '')) + 1 LOOP
  6        l_item := regexp_substr(p_tsv, '[^|]+', 1, i);
  7        dbms_output.put_line(l_item);
  8     END LOOP;
  9  END;
 10  /

23
12.1
450
30
9
78
82.5
92.1
120
185
52
11

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

#### Update

You **only** have 12 columns, I would write the query direcly without a loop, it will be more performant and easier to maintain than dynamic SQL (not to mention infinitely easier to write):

```
INSERT INTO your_table
   (ID, month1, month2, month3...)
   SELECT :p_id, 
          regexp_substr(:p_tsv, '[^|]+', 1, 1) c1, 
          regexp_substr(:p_tsv, '[^|]+', 1, 2) c2,
          regexp_substr(:p_tsv, '[^|]+', 1, 3) c3
          ...
     FROM dual;
```

Comment: Thanks Vincent, your post is helpful, but that does not address the whole problem. It is not parsing the string that is the problem as much as it is inserting them into the columns respectively.

As in what could be added into the loop to insert the values one column at a time? or insert them all into a record in a separate table?

I think that the fact that all columns end with something like an index (month1, month2, month3...) there should be a way to access and update them independently in the loop.

Thanks

Comment: @DMS: I would not use dynamic SQL in such a case. A single statement is the way to go, both for performance reason and code maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's something already defined.

There are few implementations at [orafaq](http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/11692/0/) and I found [this](http://it.toolbox.com/wiki/index.php/Splitting_string_Oracle_PL/SQL) also.

Answer (score 0):

I had 99 problems
So I used regular expressions
Now I have 100 problems
hahahahahahaha
just concatenate the delim onto beginning & end of string

pure sql solution:

```
set define on
undefine string
undefine delim
undefine nth
accept string prompt 'Enter the string: '
accept delim prompt 'Enter the delimiter: '
accept nth prompt 'Enter nth: '
select '&&string' as string,
       '&&delim' as delimiter, 
        &&nth||decode(&&nth,1,'st',2,'nd',3,'rd','th') as nth,
 substr('&&delim'||'&&string'||'&delim',
        instr('&&delim'||'&&string'||'&&delim', '&&delim', 1, &&nth ) + length('&&delim'),
        instr('&&delim'||'&&string'||'&&delim', '&&delim', 1, &&nth + 1 ) - instr('&&delim'||'&&string'||'&&delim', '&&delim', 1, &&nth ) - length('&&delim')
       ) as val from dual
```

/