# Parsing pipe delimited, irregular strings in Oracle

Tags: regex, oracle

I have data and a similar problem to this question: [Parsing pipe delimited string into columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942052/parsing-pipe-delimited-string-into-columns)

However my data can contain sub strings with no data, or strings that are incomplete. Note that 5 values is the maximum. The solution in the question above fails unless the string has 5 values. See below:

```
KEY         VALUE                               
----        -------------------
00          val1||||val5                                
01          val2|val2|val3|                        
02          val1|val2||val4
```

Comment: What is the output that you want?  One row with five columns?  Between 0 ad 5 rows with two columns?  Something else?  I'm not sure what you're trying with, presumably, `regexp_substr` and what "fails".

Comment: I need the value column split on the delimiters into 5 columns.
`select regexp_substr('val1|val2|||val5', '[^|]+', 1, 3) from dual` results in `val5` as it's the 3rd value according to the criteria. My goal is to move this data into a purposed table.

Comment: It would be helpful if you edited that into your question (both the code you're using and the output you want given that input data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME ( KEY, VALUE ) AS
SELECT '00',          'val1||||val5' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '01',          'val2|val2|val3|' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '02',          'val1|val2||val4' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT  Key,
        REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '([^|]*)(\||$)', 1, 1, NULL, 1 ) AS val1,
        REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '([^|]*)(\||$)', 1, 2, NULL, 1 ) AS val2,
        REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '([^|]*)(\||$)', 1, 3, NULL, 1 ) AS val3,
        REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '([^|]*)(\||$)', 1, 4, NULL, 1 ) AS val4,
        REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '([^|]*)(\||$)', 1, 5, NULL, 1 ) AS val5
FROM    table_name
```

**Results**:

```
KEY VAL1            VAL2            VAL3            VAL4            VAL5          
--- --------------- --------------- --------------- --------------- ---------------
00  val1                                                            val5            
01  val2            val2            val3                                            
02  val1            val2                            val4
```

Comment: Thanks, this appears to work. Could you please help me understand your usage of the match and subexpression params and the second capture group? Why doesn't a single `end with |` work the same way?

Comment: To match an empty string between `||` you need to change from `[^|]+` to a zero-width match `[^|]*`. However, this has the side effect of creating two matches when you have `|val|` - a match for `val` and then an unwanted zero-width match before the delimiter; to get round this you need to ensure you include the delimiter in the match `[^|]*\|` but that won't match the last value so you need to either match a delimiter or the end-of-string `[^|]*(\||$)`. Which gives you what you want but includes the delimiter so you can use a capturing group just to extract the required value `([^|]*)(\||$)`.

Answer (score 1):

If using PL/SQL and a loop is OK you could use apex_util.string_to_table:

```
declare
   l_tab apex_application_global.vc_arr2;
begin
   for r in (select key, value from mytable) loop
      l_tab := apex_util.string_to_table (r.value, '|');
      dbms_output.put_line ('key='||r.key);
      for i in 1..l_tab.count loop
         dbms_output.put_line ('value ' || i || '='||l_tab(i));
      end loop;
   end loop;
end;
```